# Flexbox правильное выравнивание по вертикали

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox, выравнивание

Есть флекс контейнер (*posts__cards*) в нем находятся несколько флекс блоков (*card*)  с разными размерами по высоте. Нужно, чтобы они выравнивались по вертикали как на макете:  [image: Как должно быть]
но, чтобы я не прописывал получается вот так: [image: Как получается] Пробовал сделать через *flex-direction: column;* - тоже не получалось. 
Как решить проблему?

```css
.posts__cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 180px;
}

.posts__cards .card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 32%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="posts__cards">
  <div class="card">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/blog-img-1.jpg" alt="">
      <h2>This is blog post title</h2>
      <div class="card__separator"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed blanditiis, totam incidunt? Nulla distinctio ipsum necessitatibus recusandae culpa, harum commodi.
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/blog-img-2.jpg" alt="">
      <h2>This is blog post title</h2>
      <div class="card__separator"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi enim dolor voluptas ducimus autem beatae magni, minus pariatur placeat dolorum impedit cupiditate reprehenderit magnam illum neque minima nostrum ut corporis quis? Architecto delectus
        in hic, praesentium.
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/blog-img-3.jpg" alt="">
      <h2>This is blog post title</h2>
      <div class="card__separator"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim vero temporibus a cupiditate commodi voluptatem distinctio.
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/blog-img-3.jpg" alt="">
      <h2>This is blog post title</h2>
      <div class="card__separator"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae neque architecto sit pariatur assumenda voluptate ducimus, excepturi, deleniti nisi nulla, quaerat amet non a!
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/blog-img-1.jpg" alt="">
      <h2>This is blog post title</h2>
      <div class="card__separator"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo saepe, assumenda alias odit quibusdam nihil sint!
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/blog-img-2.jpg" alt="">
      <h2>This is blog post title</h2>
      <div class="card__separator"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus tenetur, nihil ea incidunt voluptatibus dolor error, accusantium culpa. Quam iste doloremque debitis alias ad facilis aliquid officia. Eligendi, quibusdam, quod.
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: каждый столбец сунь в отдельный контейнер

Comment: Это уже сделано. В блоке posts__cards находятся 6 блоков card

Comment: уважаемый, добавь сюда нормальный пример...  здесь ясновидящих нет...  людям гадать что где у тябя и в чем?

Comment: на флексах вы так не сделаете. используйте masonry.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Максимум чего можно добиться на flex это вот. Однако проблема в том, что высоту обертки нужно ограничивать принудительно `.wrapper {max-height: 640px;}`. Так или иначе вам придется ее вычислять на js.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 640px;
}

.item {
  width: 18vw;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin: 1vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 300%;
}

.item:nth-child(2n) {
  min-height: 120px;
}

.item:nth-child(3n) {
  min-height: 80px;
}

.item:nth-child(5n) {
  min-height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
    <div class="item">11</div>
    <div class="item">12</div>
    <div class="item">13</div>
    <div class="item">14</div>
    <div class="item">15</div>
    <div class="item">16</div>
    <div class="item">17</div>
    <div class="item">18</div>
  </div>
</section>
```